# Would this power supply modification work to double the voltage?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I would like to replace the existing E-I lamination transformer with a toroid that I have.

The original transformer has windings for 48 V phantom power. I was thinking perhaps I could just tap the +/- 18 VAC windings and add caps to make a voltage doubler circuit, and then not have to change anything else?

[image]

**EDIT** Here is a circuit that I am trying to borrow from that seems to work just fine.[image]

Comment: For the transformer you probably mean 18 - 0 - 18 V.

Comment: Yes. 18-0-18 is correct. MPN: VPM36-690

Comment: From your comment on GodJihyo's answer it should be described as 0 - 18 V, 0 - 18 V which indicates that the secondaries are isolated and can be series or parallel connected.

Comment: Have you checked all of the other components to verify that they are rated for safe operation at the higher voltage?

Comment: Yes. The original transformer had a 48v tap. So everything is fine with values.

Answer (score 1):

First, that doesn't make a voltage doubler. You would need to rearrange the diodes and capacitors to get a double, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler).

Second, when specifying an AC voltage you don't say something like '+/- 18 V', that is what you would say for a bi-polar DC supply. For AC you need to specify RMS, Peak to Peak, or Peak voltage.

For a 36 VAC transformer (assuming RMS) you'll get close to 90 VDC out of a doubler, which is probably more than you'll want, so you'd need to cut it down some way.

if that 36 VAC was Peak to Peak, you'd only get around 33 VDC out, so you can see why it's important to know which way an AC voltage is specified. Peak to Peak is 2.828 times RMS.

The main problem though is that you're using the transformer as center tapped for the +/- 16 V supplies and the center tap is grounded. The phantom power is referenced to ground, so for the doubler you're considering you would only be ale to use one winding of the transformer and that isn't going to get you enough voltage. In simulation I'm seeing a single stage Cockroft-Walton giving 48 VDC from an 18 VAC winding, leaving no headroom for the regulator.

The second schematic you added isn't a voltage doubler, it's a bridge rectifier. I'm not sure what the two 470\$\mu\$F caps in series are supposed to do, but in simulation I get ~ 48.9 VDC out of this. The TL783 regulator spec sheet shows a minimum dropout voltage of around 4 V so it should need at least 52 V in. Maybe that transformer puts out a bit more than it's rated voltage, allowing the circuit to work, but it looks like it's cutting things pretty close.

Comment: Sorry, I was going for a Cockcroft–Walton (single stage). Yes, 36v ct transformer

Comment: @jackwarner Okay, I edited the answer. Can you verify whether the transformer voltage is RMS or P-P? Power transformers are usually rated RMS,, so I'm guessing that's what it is.

Comment: MPN: VPM36-690. The label says "series output 36Vac. Parallel out put 18Vac"

Comment: @jackwarner See my updates. Maybe someone else has some other thoughts on this, but it just seems borderline to me.

Comment: Just using a bridge instead of 4 discrete diodes. Would the 2nd schematic idea put a short on the AC line or would it work as is? The transformer does put out enough for it to work, but yes, the margins are very close. Phantom power does not "need" to be 48. Perhaps I could lower it to 44or 40Vdc?

Comment: perhaps you could add some turns to the toroid and and put those in series with the 18V  to get some more voltage,  you only need about 4 more volts.